# where clause with multiple criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to pull the unique employees who don't have any phone number from column "OTHER_COMMUNIC_NUM". Keep in mind when you like at the column "OTHER_COMMUNIC_C" it shows numbers 1,7,8 , which represent cell phone and home phone and work phone.

My query pull all nulls within in (1,7,8) but I want to exlude the one who has a phone number within this selection:

```
select  PAT_ID
, LINE
, OTHER_COMMUNIC_C
, OTHER_COMMUNIC_NUM 
from OTHER_COMMUNCTN 
where OTHER_COMMUNIC_C in (1,7,8)  and OTHER_COMMUNIC_NUM  is null**
```

**table

```
PAT_ID  LINE    OTHER_COMMUNIC_C    OTHER_COMMUNIC_NUM
Z10000  1         7                  957-407-5442
Z10000  2         8                  NULL
Z10000  3         1                  NULL
Z100000 1         7                  651-431-1879
Z100000 2         8                  651-431-1879
Z100000 3         1                  NULL
Z10000001         7                  856-625-6979
Z10000002         8                  NULL
Z10000003         1                  856-625-6979
```

Comment: Does something in the data refer to an "employee"?  What database are you using?

Comment: Did you try the code you wrote filtering out nulls? What happened? Why was that wrong?

Comment: I am using sql server an dthe employee=PAT_ID. sorry

Comment: Can you post your expected result?

Comment: I used that query above but it pulled all nulls even those have a numberPAT_ID LINE OTHER_COMMUNIC_NUM
Z10000         5 NULL
Z100000         3 NULL
Z1000000 2 NULL
Z1000001 6 NULL
Z1000002 6 NULL
Z1000003 2 NULL

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this:

```
select  PAT_ID
from OTHER_COMMUNCTN 
where OTHER_COMMUNIC_C in (1,7,8)  
group by PAT_ID
having count(OTHER_COMMUNIC_NUM) = 0
```

It gives you all PAT_ID where they don't have any phone number at all in any of their type 1, 7 or 8 records

If you mean "give me all PAT_ID where any one of their 1, 7 or 8 records contains a null:

```
select  PAT_ID
from OTHER_COMMUNCTN 
where OTHER_COMMUNIC_C in (1,7,8)  
group by PAT_ID
having 
  count(OTHER_COMMUNIC_NUM) < 3
```

You might need to make sure that you're only checking employees that have a 1, 7 and 8 record (i.e. an employe with only 1 and 7 records is ignored) which can be done by adding `AND sum(case OTHER_COMMUNIC_C WHEN 1 THEN 1 WHEN 7 THEN 2 WHEN 8 THEN 4 END) = 7` to your HAVING

Comment: Thank you Jard . This is exactly what I need :)